# mySQL join 3 columns from each of two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join data from two tables where the userid from table 1 is in table 2. 
I have tried multiple variations with no luck and read a dozen posts here on SO on this topic.

The data in table one has an id, username, rolerequest, and appuserid. I am selecting the last three items and trying to join 3 items from table 2 when the appserid from table 1 is equal to the userid from table 2.

here is my latest attempt;

```
SELECT username, rolerequest, appuserid
FROM userrolespending 
LEFT JOIN  my_aspnet_membership.email,my_aspnet_membership.creationdate,my_aspnet_membership.lastlogindate
where my_aspnet_membership.userid = userrolespending.appuserid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to use `LEFT JOIN` because you only want to return `userid` that are present from both tables. `INNER JOIN` returns records that the `ID` or the linking columns are both present on all tables.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*       -- <== select the columns you want to appear
FROM userrolespending a
     INNER JOIN  my_aspnet_membership b
        ON a.appserid = b.userID
```

or to be exact,

```
SELECT a.username, a.rolerequest, a.appuserid,
       b.email,b.creationdate, b.lastlogindate
FROM userrolespending a
     INNER JOIN  my_aspnet_membership b
        ON a.appserid = b.userID
```

Comment: this will retrieve all columns from each table but i only want 3 specific columns from each.

Comment: @dinotom yes, that is why I indicated that you need to select you desired columns. example, `SELECT a.username, a.rolerequest, a.appuserid, b.*...` I don't know the names of your columns.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need :

```
SELECT username, rolerequest, appuserid
FROM userrolespending 
LEFT JOIN  my_aspnet_membership
on my_aspnet_membership.userid = userrolespending.appuserid;
```

Comment: this would return all the columns from the membership table correct? I am only trying to retrieve 3 columns, email creationdate and lastlogindate

Comment: then but them in your select
example, SELECT email, creationdate,lastlogindate